# How can I convert the Defer result to a String

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, string-manipulation

I have created a package.wl where I am building a simple interface with input fields and buttons to generate and solve some simple integer logarithms.

There is a button [show solution] that explains the solution using the Defer.

```
 s1 := Defer[(numBaseLog^exp)]/.a_^n_?Positive:>RuleCondition@Table[a,n]/.List->Times;
```

where given numBaseLog = 2 and exp = 5 it prints:

```
2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2
```

When I do the Print[s1] it works correctly. When I try to assign the s1 to some string variable :

```
showCorrectSolution = s1 (*or*) showCorrectSolution=ToString[s1]    

Row[{Dynamic[showCorrectSolution]}]

Button["Clear Solution", showCorrectSolution = ""; ]
```

I want to show the solution in the dynamic row and be able to clear it with the button. But s1 only returns

```
"Null (2 2 2 2 2)"
```

I know I can't clear the Print results so this solution was the best for me.
I also tried to create another function and call assign the function to the variable but it does the same thing. Am I missing something here?
[image: Here's a screen of the interface]